# Is GroupBy based on another list possible in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Assuming that I had code like this, where each country had a list of all city IDs that belong to this country, but city objects had no information about which country they belong to, would it be possible to group cities by country?

```
public class Country
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public List<int> CityIds { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
}

List<City> cities = _database.GetAllCities();
List<Country> countries = _database.GetAllCountries();

var citiesGroupedByCountry = cities.GroupBy(.... ?);
```

Comment: If you have the reference of a `Country` on the `City` entity, you can: `cities.GroupBy(x => x.Country)`.

Comment: `cities.GroupBy(city => countries.First(country => country.CityIds.Contains(city.Id)))`?

Comment: Alternatively, since you already have a list of `CityIds` in your `Country` object, you could turn your `List<City>` into `Dictionary<int, City>` where the key is the ID of the city and the value is the city object. Then when you need to get a list of cities based on the country (which is why `GroupBy` is doing in this case), you can just reference the dictionary. This would also likely be more resource efficient and potentially faster.

Answer (score 3):

You can use anonymous and create the link inversely.

```
// get all your citites and country
List<City> cities = _database.GetAllCities();
List<Country> countries = _database.GetAllCountries();

// country are already grouped so you just need the select
var CitiesByCountry = countries.Select(country => new { Country = country, Citites = CityIds.Select(cid => cities.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == cid)).ToList()).ToList();

// read the values
var firstcountry = CitiesByCountry[0].Country;
var firstcountryCities = CitiesByCountry[0].Cities;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple where clause since you already have CityIds grouped by Country in the `Country` object

pseudo code:

```
public class Country
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public List<int> CityIds { get; set; }
  public string Name{get;set;}
}

public class City
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name{get;set;}
}

public class MockData
{
    public List<City> GetAllCities()
    {
        return new List<City>(){ new City(){ Id = 11, Name="Delhi"}, new City(){  Id = 22, Name="Mumbai"} };
    }
    
    public List<Country> GetAllCountries()
    {
        return new List<Country>(){ new Country(){ Id=1, Name="India", CityIds = new List<int>(){ 11,22 } } };
    }
}


void Main()
{
    var _database = new MockData();
    List<City> cities = _database.GetAllCities();
    List<Country> countries = _database.GetAllCountries();

    var citiesGroupedByCountry = from p in countries
                                 select new{ Country=p, Cities = cities.Where(x=> p.CityIds.Contains(x.Id)) };
    Console.Write(citiesGroupedByCountry);                               
}
```

[image: glaga blag blag]